# Concatenate hex numeric updowns to string for a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 numeric up down controls on a form.  They are set to hexidecimal, maximum 255, so they'll each have values from 0 to FF.  I'd like to concatenate these values into a string for a textbox.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Do it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you gave the NUDs their default names:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string txt = "";
  for (int ix = 1; ix <= 4; ++ix) {
    var nud = Controls["numericUpDown" + ix] as NumericUpDown;
    int hex = (int)nud.Value;
    txt += hex.ToString("X2");
  }
  textBox1.Text = txt;
}
```

Comment: No use writing so much code for so-less-details? questions :)

Comment: When I use the resulting textbox text in this code:
int param = int.Parse(txtARGB.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
it results in a Format Exception was unhandled message:
Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: @Jimmy: you have to use NumberStyles.HexNumber.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for the link. I know this stuff, more or less. I was just joking :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", 
        (int)numericUpDown1.Value, 
        (int)numericUpDown2.Value,
        (int)numericUpDown3.Value,
        (int)numericUpDown4.Value);
```